# Graduate level linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation

Basically, I have a few related questions. The first one may seem a little naive, so please forgive me.

Is there much linear algebra to be taught beyond the level of books like Axler or Friedberg, Insel, and Spence? Is linear algebra typically taught beyond this advanced undergraduate/early graduate level, or would it just start to become abstract algebra and/or functional analysis?

If linear algebra is indeed taught at the graduate level, I would love some recommendations for some of the most commonly used textbooks.

I hope I phrased my question clearly and correctly, this is my first time posting here.

Comment: On the algebraic side, it turns into module theory. The classification of finitely generated modules over a PID is a good example and is covered in comprehensive introductions to abstract algebra, e.g. Dummit and Foote. You could argue homological algebra is a form of advanced linear algebra, e.g. Weibel. But I have not heard of "advanced linear algebra" _per se_ being taught at the graduate level from an algebraic perspective. I'm less qualified to speak in the analytic direction, and so will not.

Comment: In my experience "graduate level linear algebra" is mainly [module theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)), which is all about doing linear algebra over general rings. Modules are the main object of study in [commutative algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_algebra), and any book with that title will be good. Some quick recommendations that I'm sure you'll find are the (excellent and short) text by Atiyah and Macdonald as well as the (excellent and long) text by Eisenbud.

Comment: There's a whole rich subject of numerical linear algebra. See the book by Trefethen, for example, or Golub and Van Loan.

Comment: Other commenters have gotten at this. But I will summarize (1) Many linear algebraic techniques generalize beyond fields, with appropriate modification, (2) Numerical linear algebra is an entire universe that is not adequately dealt with in most undergraduate curricula. I would also add (3) Functional analysis and operator theory often attempt to generalize linear algebra to infinite dimensional settings where many of the finite dimensional arguments don't work, but it's often still "linear algebraic" in feeling.

Comment: @JoshM Three textbooks used for linear algebra at the graduate level: *Matrix Analysis* and *Topics in Matrix Analysis* by Horn and Johnson, and *Matrix Analysis* by Rajendra Bhatia.

Comment: As I said in answerng your other question, the order you learn things in in math isn't necessarily always ideal for a future mathematician, for various reasons. From a pure math standpoint, it makes sense to study abstract algebra and linear algebra in tandem. Two books that take this approach are *Algebra* by Artin and *Algebra* by Godement.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, after  linear algebra, which studies finite dimensional vector spaces, it is possible to study infinite dimensional vector spaces, however this is part of functional analysis:

> 1. Haim Brezis-Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial differential equations.
> 2. Peter D. Lax-Functional analysis-Wiley (2002)

The second book (P. Lax) begins with a vector normed spaces and to my liking it is very constructive.

On the other hand, you can study linear algebra in more depth, seeing specific topics such as matrix analysis.

> 1. Carl D. Meyer-Matrix analysis and applied linear algebra. With solutions to problems-Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics (2001).
> 2. Philip N. Klein-Coding the matrix. Linear algebra through computer science Applications-Newtonian Press (2013) *(Especific topic)*

In addition, linear algebra has important applications in optimization, where convex sets, polyhedra, etc. are studied. Or in the probability in discrete Markov chains